# Does alacrity affect GCD in swtor?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Does the alactrity or "activation speed" stat decrease GCD in swtor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, the global cool down is not effected, except in the case of cast-time abilities.

Source: http://sithwarrior.com/forums/Thread-Alacrity-and-the-GCD

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. As of game update 2.0 Alacrity was improved. It now affects resource regeneration and the global cooldown.

Source: http://www.swtor.com/info/news/blog/20130417-0

And as of game update 3.0 alacrity also affects over-time effects and everything else. A character with 10% alacrity should be 10% faster in everything.

Comment: Note also that as of 3.0, Alacrity affects *everything*.  Tick speed of your DoTs, internal (proc) cooldowns, ability cooldowns, etc.